# Convert to ASCII char in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

In Oracle I can convert `ÄÊÍABCDE` to `AEIABCDE` using:

```
SELECT CONVERT('ÄÊÍABCDE', 'US7ASCII') from dual;
```

Output:

```
AEIABCDE
```

How can I do the same in SQL Server?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can try following query:

```
 SELECT CAST('ÄÊÍABCDE' AS varchar(100)) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI
```

**Caveat:**

This does not support UNICODE strings so do not replace `varchar` with `nvarchar`

demo sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/2016

**Explanation:**

Read about collate on MSDN here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx

**Edit:**

On comment

> if 'ÄÊÍABCDE' = CAST('ÄÊÍABCDE' AS varchar(100)) COLLATE
>   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI print 'same' else print 'not same'
>   prints same. Why??

Collation is forced in the `WHERE` condition which collates both side of comparison. If you need `not same` as result, try below

```
declare @t varchar
set @t= CAST('ÄÊÍABCDE' AS varchar(100)) 
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI
select 
case 
when 'ÄÊÍABCDE' like  @t
then 'same' else  'not same' end as result
```

demo link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/2022

Comment: `if 'ÄÊÍABCDE' = CAST('ÄÊÍABCDE' AS varchar(100)) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI
print 'same'
else print 'not same'` prints `same`.   Why??

Answer (score 4):

[Answer to the question in comment from 'Praveen']

As explained in the answer by DhruvJoshi, the collation is forced on both the sides.

To work around this problem, you could create a function (that performs the collation) which takes the '**string to be collated**' as argument and returns **collated string**.

You could then call the function on one side of the check condition.

The function may look something like this:

```
create function dbo.convert_ascii(@input nvarchar(500))
returns varchar(500)
as
begin
declare @collatedstring varchar(500)
set @collatedstring = CAST(@input AS varchar(100)) 
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI
return @collatedstring 
end
```

And you could invoke it this way:

```
if 'ÄÊÍABCDE' = dbo.convert_ascii('ÄÊÍABCDE')
print 'same' 
else 
print 'not same'
```

This should work.