# SQL Server ability to convert EBCDIC character set

Tags: sql-server, ebcdic

Is MS SQL Server able to convert data into EBCDIC characer set. I would prefer EBCDIC 500 if possible.

I'm wondering if there is an alternative to the ORACLE CONVERT function. See the following ORACE statement if would need rewrite to SQL Server dialect.

**Convert function:**

```
SELECT CONVERT('Ä Ê Í Õ Ø A B C D E 123456 abcde ;!@#$%^&*()_+', 'WE8ISO8859P1', 'US7ASCII') FROM DUAL;
```

**EDIT: The Examples on ORACLE Convert function including expected results**

**Example 1:**

```
SELECT CONVERT('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFHGIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 0123456789 ~!@#$%^&*()_+=-[]{};:,./" Ä Ê Í Ó Ø', 'WE8EBCDIC500', 'AL32UTF8') FROM DUAL; 
-- returns: @{[l_P\M]mN~`JZ^zkKa@c@r@u@
-- some non-visible chars has been stipped
```

**Example 2:**

```
SELECT CONVERT('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFHGIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 0123456789 ~!@#$%^&*()_+=-[]{};:,./" Ä Ê Í Ó Ø', 'AL32UTF8', 'WE8EBCDIC500') FROM DUAL; 
-- returns: /ÂÄÀÁÃÅÇÑ¦,%_>?øÉÊËÈÍÎÏÌ`: âäàáãçåñ[.<(+!&éêëèíîïìß]
-- some non-visible chars has been stipped
```

**Example 3:**

```
SELECT CONVERT('/¦,%_>øÉÊËÈÍÎÏÌ`:âäàáãçåñ[.+!]', 'WE8EBCDIC500', 'AL32UTF8') FROM DUAL; 
-- returns: ajklmnpqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFHGIJKNOZ Ä Ê Í Ó Ø
-- some non-visible chars has been stipped
```

**Screenshot from Oracle Developer Studio:**

[image]

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32367311/convert-to-ascii-char-in-sql-server

Comment: Suggested QA didn't help, the statement SELECT CAST('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFHGIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 0123456789 ~!@#$%^&*()_+=-[]{};:,./" Ä Ê Í Ó Ø' AS varchar(100)) COLLATE SQL_EBCDIC037_CP1_CS_AS; returns the same charaters. As far as I understand, it is just a sorting order, but no conversion, right?

Comment: can you please show (at least picture) what is the expected result?

Comment: Edit: Added exmples on ORACLE Convert functions with expect results, including screenshots showing presence of 'non-visible' characters.

Comment: It is VERY unclear what is your expected result. Every query you provided have different encodings with different results. Please show which 1 is the expected one.