# Spark SQL - convert string to ASCII

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, ansi-sql

we have an issue of one of the producers pushing some Unicode strings to a field which should be ASCII. Currently the job is pure-sql configurable hence I would like to know if it's possible to convert Unicode string to ASCII using just Spark SQL, something similar to solution given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32367311/convert-to-ascii-char-in-sql-server) question (of course this will result in possible data loss for unsupported characters, but this is not a concern).

Comment: What's the expected result if non-ASCII characters are passed? Do you really want a Chinese input to become empty?

Comment: No issues with that but thanks for raising the concern :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try `encode`:

```
SELECT encode(column, 'ascii') as column;
```

for example:

```
spark-sql> select encode('ÄÊÍABCDE', 'ascii');
???ABCDE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the unwanted chars using the regexp_replace()

```
scala> spark.sql(""" SELECT regexp_replace(decode(encode('Ä??ABCDE', 'utf-8'), 'ascii'), "[^\t\n\r\x20-\x7F]","")  x """).show(false)
+-----+
|x    |
+-----+
|ABCDE|
+-----+


scala>
```